# "An error occurred submitting the question" in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow, questions, asking-questions

For a few weeks now since I registered my account on Stack Overflow I have not been able to post questions or answers.

I have gone through similar/duplicate questions here on Meta about this issue, but in my case…

1. no further information about the error is displayed, only that there is an error.
2. I can't publish no matter the content. I have seen many related questions concerning codes which contained SQL queries, and that was the source of the problem.
3. I am not publishing beyond character limit.

Thus I have not found an answer here on Meta about what could possibly be causing this error. It only makes sense that it is something regarding my network, connection or browser, but I am clueless.

In the most recent example, I am trying to submit this question, which contains no code at all:

> My goal is to create a window using the "namedWindow" environment in which an image is shown, and make that window's size freely modifiable manually (with the user's cursor). Eg. think of MATLAB's figures where one can completely resize at will. What would the simplest approach to this issue be?

Why can't I post anything at all?

Please see in this figure a screenshot of the error:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is it your **first** question?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with the post (title, body, tags) and the error displayed, please?

Comment: Be specific about what it shows you when you try to post, or what is exactly happening.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani Yes, that would have been my first question in StackOverflow. Added screenshot, sorry for not doing it beforehand!

Comment: I have the same problem...2 years later... did anybody find the answer to this question ?

Comment: @ZakC In my case, for some reason it was trying to submit over HTTP when the page was loaded over HTTPS.